# Можно ли использовать один engine для всего сервера?

Tags: python, python-3.x, производительность, sqlalchemy, asyncio

Существует веб-сервер на `aiohttp` с использованием `async`. Использую `sqlalchemy` и тут возникает вопрос, почти каждый `handler` соединяется с БД (`mysql`), могу ли я использовать один `sqlalchemy.engine.Engine`(подключив его через `builtins`) для всех `handler` для всевозможных execute? На сколько это будет эффективно, по сравнению с тем что бы каждый раз выполнять `sqlalchemy.create_engine()` ? Не будут ли асинхронные запросы мешать друг другу и создавать проблемы ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не только можете, но и должны. Создавать пул соединений для каждого запроса - это плохое решение. Но стоит учесть, что SQLAlchemy по умолчанию синхронная, а значит, что без дополнительных ухищрений весь ваш сервер становится синхронным. [Вот как этот вопрос решает сам автор aiohttp.](http://asvetlov.blogspot.ru/2014/05/aiopgsa.html)